# Change part of csv string panda

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, output

I would like to change the word consolidation (two times in the following string) with an other value with a variable or ? (ex. breakout/outofconsolidation/inside)

Can I help me to achieve this, please?

```
dfconsolidationcsv.to_csv(r'symbols\stocks_consolidation_sp500.csv', index = False)

a = ('breakout')
df{a}csv.to_csv(r'symbols\stocks_{a}_sp500.csv', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a justifiable reason to be creating dynamic variable assignments, I would avoid doing so. In this case, defining your DataFrame variables in a dict is probably sufficient:

```
# store df in a dict instead of separate variables
df_dict = dict()
df_dict['consolidation'] = dfconslidationcv
df_dict['breakout'] = dfbreakoutcv
...

# invoke command for a specific variable
a = 'breakout'
df_dict[a].to_csv(r'symbols\stocks_%s_sp500.csv' % a, index = False)
```

Now, if there is an overwhelming reason why you HAVE to use pre-existing variable names that need to be changed dynamically, I think you can do something like this:

```
a = 'breakout'
exec("df%scsv.to_csv(r'symbols\stocks_%s_sp500.csv', index=False)" % (a, a))
```

Comment: I would like to change the variable dynamically. But exec seems to be not a solution because it seems to be unsecure. Is there an other solution to change some values in a string dynamically without exec? Thanks for your effort.